Weekly topic challenge for the week of January 1, 2012: Asset Allocation
This week's topic challenge is Asset Allocation. You're encouraged to think of and post good questions on this topic.
What is it?
There's a single topic that people think about during the week and come up with good questions on. The topic is set each Sunday or so.
How does it work?
The topic is chosen from among proposals on Sunday, and the challenge begins: thinking of and posting good questions in the main site on that topic.
What do I win?
An Internet with more good questions and answers on an interesting topic.
Who thought of this week's topic, anyway?
SRKX did.
How do we decide on next week's topic?
See the call for topic proposals.

Lot of pressure on me now to come up with something good...

7 new questions with the tag asset-allocation were asked during the weekly topic challenge.  Of these, SRKX's question, How do you mix quantitative asset allocation with qualitative views? got the most upvotes.  Tal Fishman's question, How to shift amongst asset classes in response to relative value views?, got the most views.
Thanks to everyone for your participation!
